# asp.net mvc httpclient save cookies after post to another website

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have controller that use HttpClient and post data to another website. After POST httpclient have cookies, which I must use to send another GET for this site. Something like this:

```
private async Task LogIn()
{
    HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
    await client.PostAsync(data);
//  after this I have handler.CookieContainter and I need save this cookies, because I don't need login again until cookie not expired
}
```

I need save this cookie in server and each time when I send GET to this site I need get saved cookie and if they not expired I must use it.
But I don't know how to save this, because any my user must use this this cookie.